# Geniune channel server in a windows service?

Tags: c#, networking, .net-remoting

I am developping a server with geniune channel in a windows service , it seems that it's not as simple as the console application. When the thread that  creates the server finishes his job , all variables that were declared in the thread scope are destroyed so the client cannot connect to that server anymore. With Console application we can avoid that with console.readline() but it's not the same case for windows service. So the first block of code is for windows service thread that creates the server and the second one is for the console application.

```
public void startServer()
{
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("DNS");
 GenuineGlobalEventProvider.GenuineChannelsGlobalEvent += new GenuineChannelsGlobalEventHandler(GenuineChannelsEventHandler);
 var Path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
 RemotingConfiguration.Configure(Path + "Server.exe.config");
 RemotingServices.Marshal(new Agent(), "Server.rem");
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("DNS");
 GenuineGlobalEventProvider.GenuineChannelsGlobalEvent += new GenuineChannelsGlobalEventHandler(GenuineChannelsEventHandler);
 var Path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
 RemotingConfiguration.Configure(Path + "Server.exe.config");
 RemotingServices.Marshal(new Agent(), "Server.rem");
 Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Have I missed somthing ? How can i achieve the availability of the server ?

Comment: The question here is...?

Comment: Hi , I edit the question :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to store the `Agent` in your service class when `Start` is called and dispose of it in the service shutdown when `Stop` is called.

On a side note, if that's the problem, there's no good reason your console app works either.  C# isn't C++, there are no destructors that are called when you leave scope.  Also, why remoting instead of something more supported?

Comment: Because i need to create a bidirectionnel TCP communication between Client and Server without opening two ports on both side. 
.Net Remoting is Firewall Friendly.

Comment: Ha, that's funny, usually I hear people say that we should stop using remoting and switch to WCF for the same reason.  What a life we're living.